# "from django... import..." unresolved import error

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, python-import, pipenv

I'm following a Django crash course, and all there is right now are the `__init__.py`, `settings.py`, `urls.py`, `wsgi.py` in the project folder, as well as `manage.py`. Django is already installed through pipenv.

In both `urls.py` and `wsgi.py`, there's are imports from Django

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'pollster.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

respectively.

The error that shows up is `unresolved import 'django.core.wsgi'Python(unresolved-import)` for all of the Django imports. I don't understand why, because with the VSCode Python shell shows no error when doing `import django` or any of the `from django import...`

I've searched on Stackoverflow and it seems that this isn't really a problem and I've also reinstalled django, but I'm still not sure what exactly `unresolved import` means or what to do about it.

Here's the repo: https://github.com/davidDongGithub/project-holdings.git

Comment: Did you try re-installing the django on your virtualenv?

Comment: My guess is that you have a file/folder named `django`.

Comment: @TomWojcik I have no other folder in the project named `django`.

Comment: @DavidDong can you post to a link to GitHub repo because right now it's a little bit hard to guess where the problem is?

Comment: @funnydman I've added it.

Comment: @DavidDong I deployed it locally and it works just fine. Try to recreate virtualenv.

Comment: What do you mean that "the VSCode Python shell shows no error". How are you executing the code in the terminal? Does that match the environment you have selected in VS Code?